# Pass data from SQLite to RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I want to pass some data from an SQLite DB to a RecyclerView, but unfortunately my app crashes, and I don't know how to proceed to achieve my goal.
For the moment, my app shows the elements in the DB inside an AlertDialog, but I want to display them in a RecyclerView.

Here's my code:

The following is the Activity where the user inserts data:

```
public class InserimentoScadenze extends AppCompatActivity {
//dichiaro il db
DbHelperAdapter.ScadenzeDbHelper myDB;
EditText et1, et2, et3;
Button btnAddInfo, btnViewInfo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inserimento_scadenze);
    /**lo istanzio, così mi richiama il costruttore nella classe
     * del DbHelper così da poter creare le tabelle
     */

    myDB = new DbHelperAdapter.ScadenzeDbHelper(this);

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTipo);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNote);
    et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    btnAddInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd );
    btnViewInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    addInfo();
    viewAll();
}

public void addInfo(){

    btnAddInfo.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    boolean isInserted = myDB.insertInfo(et1.getText().toString(),
                            et2.getText().toString(),
                            et3.getText().toString());

                    if(isInserted == true){

                        Toast.makeText(InserimentoScadenze.this, "Le informazioni sono state inserite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        et1.setText("");
                        et2.setText("");
                        et3.setText("");


                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(InserimentoScadenze.this, "Errore durante l'inserimento" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        et1.setText("");
                        et2.setText("");
                        et3.setText("");

                    }
                }
            }
    );
}

public void viewAll(){
    btnViewInfo.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor result = myDB.getAllInfo();
                    if(result.getCount() == 0){

                        //mostra un messaggio
                        showMessage("Errore","Nessun risultato trovato");
                        return;

                    }


                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                    while (result.moveToNext()){
                        buffer.append("Id :"+ result.getString(0)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Tipo :"+ result.getString(1)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Note :"+ result.getString(2)+"\n");
                        buffer.append("Data  :"+ result.getString(3)+"\n\n ");
                    }

                    showMessage("Info",buffer.toString() );


                }
            }
    );
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message)  {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();

}

public void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllInfo();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

This is my DbHelperAdapter:

```
public class DbHelperAdapter {
static ScadenzeDbHelper helper;

public DbHelperAdapter(Context context) {
    helper = new ScadenzeDbHelper(context);
}

public long insetData(String tipo, String note, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, tipo);
    contentValues.put(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, note);
    contentValues.put(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4, date);
    long id = db.insert(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return id;
}


public List<CardInfo> getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    List<CardInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] columns = {ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if(cursor != null){

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int cid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1));
            String tipo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2));
            String note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4));
            buffer.append(cid + " " + tipo + " " + note + " " + date + "\n");

        }

    }


    return list;
}

public static List<CardInfo> getAllData_a() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    List<CardInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor != null){

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int cid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1));
            String tipo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2));
            String note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4));
            CardInfo current = new CardInfo();
            current.id = cid;
            current.tipo = tipo;
            current.note = note;
            current.date = date;
            data.add(current);
        }

    }


    return data;

}

public static String getData(String tipo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2 + " = '" + tipo + "' ", null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if(cursor != null){

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String TipoNota = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2));
            String nota = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4));
            buffer.append(TipoNota + " " + nota + " " + date + "\n");
        }

    }

    return buffer.toString();
}

static class ScadenzeDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scadenze.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scadenze_table";

    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "TIPO";
    public static final String COL_3 = "NOTE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "DATA";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table \" + TABLE_NAME + \"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIPO TEXT, NOTE TEXT, DATA TEXT) \"";

    private Context context;


    public ScadenzeDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        /**
         * il metodo qui immediatamente sotto esegue qualsiasi query gli si passi
         * come parametro, accetta una String, o anche String Query
         */
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertInfo(String tipo, String note, String data) {
        //costruttore
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, tipo);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, note);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, data);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;

        }


    }

    public Cursor getAllInfo() {
        //costruttore
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return result;

    }

}}
```

And this is my Adapter class:

```
public class DbHelperAdapter {

static ScadenzeDbHelper helper;

public DbHelperAdapter(Context context) {
    helper = new ScadenzeDbHelper(context);
}

public long insetData(String tipo, String note, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, tipo);
    contentValues.put(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, note);
    contentValues.put(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4, date);
    long id = db.insert(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return id;
}


public List<CardInfo> getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    List<CardInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] columns = {ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if(cursor != null){

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int cid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1));
            String tipo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2));
            String note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4));
            buffer.append(cid + " " + tipo + " " + note + " " + date + "\n");

        }

    }


    return list;
}

public static List<CardInfo> getAllData_a() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    List<CardInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor != null){

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int cid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_1));
            String tipo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2));
            String note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4));
            CardInfo current = new CardInfo();
            current.id = cid;
            current.tipo = tipo;
            current.note = note;
            current.date = date;
            data.add(current);
        }

    }


    return data;

}

public static String getData(String tipo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ScadenzeDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2 + " = '" + tipo + "' ", null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if(cursor != null){

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String TipoNota = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_2));
            String nota = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_3));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScadenzeDbHelper.COL_4));
            buffer.append(TipoNota + " " + nota + " " + date + "\n");
        }

    }

    return buffer.toString();
}

static class ScadenzeDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scadenze.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scadenze_table";

    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "TIPO";
    public static final String COL_3 = "NOTE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "DATA";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table \" + TABLE_NAME + \"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIPO TEXT, NOTE TEXT, DATA TEXT) \"";

    private Context context;


    public ScadenzeDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        /**
         * il metodo qui immediatamente sotto esegue qualsiasi query gli si passi
         * come parametro, accetta una String, o anche String Query
         */
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertInfo(String tipo, String note, String data) {
        //costruttore
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, tipo);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, note);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, data);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;

        }


    }

    public Cursor getAllInfo() {
        //costruttore
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return result;

    }

}}
```

This is the logcat of the crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.alessandrocucci.cardrecyclerview/it.alessandrocucci.cardrecyclerview.InserimentoScadenze}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: """ (code 1): , while compiling: create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIPO TEXT, NOTE TEXT, DATA TEXT) "
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: """ (code 1): , while compiling: create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIPO TEXT, NOTE TEXT, DATA TEXT) "
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:58
```

Comment: use simple adapter like this:  https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59 or https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b or https://gist.github.com/kyze8439690/8982011e142f17950120 why to make your life harder?

Comment: OK, I found your error. See my answer below.

Comment: Ok but, the problem is that i have no idea how to use that CursorRecyclerViewAdapter. Any suggestions?

Comment: there is a constructor to use that uses your Cursor and implement abstract `onBindViewHolderCursor` / `onBindViewHolder` method where you set your Views with a Cursor data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your table creation:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table \" + TABLE_NAME + \"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIPO TEXT, NOTE TEXT, DATA TEXT) \"";
```

Should be

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TIPO TEXT, NOTE TEXT, DATA TEXT)";
```

You used the escape characters in a randomic way.

Comment: Thank you, it works: it doesn't crashes anymore. Now, my Question is: How can i display all the data in a RecyclerView?

Comment: Of course. If you can display it in a ListView, then you can do the same in a RecyclerView as well.

Comment: The problem is that i don't display it in a ListView, beacause I have never tried before (I have started programming only few months ago) so i thought that using the RecyclerView was a better idea

Comment: Yes, it is. It's **faster**. Simply fill an adapter and assign it to the RecyclerView. But this is another question.